# Excel Shapes Disappear When I Move or Copy a Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I have a sheet in an Excel 2003 (xls) workbook that has numerous textbox shapes in.

If I move the sheet or copy it to another workbook, the textboxes don't move with the sheet. Everything else appears to be working correctly, but the textboxes are missing in the new sheet.

I tested this with other sheets and everything works as expected. Textboxes and other shapes get moved with the sheet.

I also confirmed that File > Options > Advanced > Cut, copy and paste > Cut, copy and sort inserted objects with their parent cells is enabled (checked). Too, right-clicking on the shape, selecting Format Shape > Properties > Object Positioning is set to Move and size with cells.

What could be causing the shapes to disappear when I move or copy the sheet?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think this had something to do with compatibility mode. I have not been able to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Go to: Excel options > Advance > Cut, copy, and paste(section) > Check box for "Cut, copy, and sort inserted objects with their parent cells"

Comment: Thank you. I was having this issue as described and this was the solution.  I think that option became unchecked on an upgrade from 2016 -> 360